# How do I get equal and not equal value between two list using Linq lambda expression

Tags: c#

I have two lists one is the object and other is the list of string split by `,` separated string.

I have one object

```
class objectA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

and other is

```
String IDs = "2,10,40,35,51,68";
List<string> ListID = IDs.Split(',').ToList();
```

I need to get the common IDs from both the list and get the IDs from the `ListID` which is not in the `List<objectA>`. Can anyone help me to implement it on LINQ lambda expression? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the class have to do with your question?

Comment: @sayse cannot I create List of that class.

Comment: @AjitBoyite you can, but explain the details in question itself, currently it doesn't provide a clear picture, which two list you are referring to

Comment: @MrinalKamboj One is List<objectA> and ListID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enumerable.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) can give you the IDs that occur in both lists. e.g.

```
id_list.Select(x => x.ID.ToString()).Intersect(ListID)
```

[Enumerable.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2) can give you the IDs in the first list that do not occur in the second. e.g.

```
ListID.Except(id_listSelect(x => x.ID.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can select from one of the lists where the other contains the id:

```
myClassList.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.ID).Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

In order to get the ids not in the list, negate the `Contains()`:

```
myClassList.Where(x => !idList.Contains(x.ID).Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

A check to ensure if all elements are integers:

```
int tempVal;
if(ListId.All(j => int.TryParse(j, out tempVal)))
{
// All data2 strings are int's
var newData = ListOfObjects.Select(a => a.Id).Intersect(ListId.Select(s => int.Parse(s));
}
```